# express.js server running on nodemon working differently than one on node

Tags: node.js, postman, nodemon

my <kbd>server.js</kbd> looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

var ingredients = [
    {
        id:"i1",
        text:'eggs'
    },
    {
        id:'i2',
        text:'milk'
    },
    {
        id:'i3',
        text:'bacon'
    },
    {
        id:'i4',
        text:'frog legs'
    }
];
app.get('/',function (request,response){
    response.send(ingredients);
});
app.post('/',function(request,response){
    var ingredient = request.body;
    if( !ingredient || ingredient.text===""){
        response.status(500).send({error: "Your ingredient must have some text"});
    }else {
        ingredients.push(ingredient);
        response.status(200).send(ingredients);
    }
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
    /* body... */
    console.log('My first API running successfully on port 3000');
});
```

so when I run the server using <kbd>node server.js</kbd> and send a <kbd>POST</kbd> request with the body text as

```
{"id":"i5","text":"cherries"}
```

It pushes the object to the <kbd>ingredients</kbd> array. But when I run the same file using <kbd>nodemon server.js</kbd> , it pushes an empty object. Also, it doesn't return an error message if <kbd>"text"</kbd> property is left empty(also in the nodemon scenario). Can anyone from the community help me understand why did this happen ?

P.S. - I tested the requests using POSTMAN.

Comment: Does the solution work for you ? if you mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are pushing blank object in array is you are not passing `application/json` on header .

And also your condition of checking text is not right.

```
 var ingredient = request.body;
    if( !ingredient || ingredient.text===""){
```

//when you assign `request.body` to `ingredient` if no data come it assign `{}` to it and when you check for `if` condition `!ingredient`  is not blank it has `{}` and in next condition `ingredient.text` return `undefined` which is not equal to `""`

```
app.post('/',function(request,response){
    console.log("post");
    var ingredient = request.body;
    if (!('text' in ingredient)){
   // if(ingredient.text){
        response.status(500).send({error: "Your ingredient must have some text"});
    }else {
         console.log("post1",ingredient);
        ingredients.push(ingredient);
        response.status(200).send(ingredients);
    }
});
```